# Get some cryptocurrency rates from coingecko api

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning some aspects of PEP8 and Python programming in general. Could you please code-review this little piece of code for me? I would be glad to hear any, even the smallest comments, thanks!

```
from array import array
from typing import NamedTuple
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
savedTokensArray = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum']

class CryptoCurrency(NamedTuple):
    currencyName: str
    currencyPrice: float


def get_tokens_price(tokenIds: array) -> dict[str, float]:
    tokens = None
    for token in tokenIds:
        tokens = f'{tokens}, {token}'
    tokensList = cg.get_price(ids=tokens, vs_currencies='usd')
    data = [CryptoCurrency(currencyName=currency, currencyPrice=tokensList[currency]['usd']) for currency in tokensList]
    currencysDict = {}
    for token in data:
        currencysDict[token.currencyName] = token.currencyPrice

    return currencysDict


resultDict = get_tokens_price(savedTokensArray)
print(resultDict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, PEP8 suggests using `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for regular variable names, so you should rename those.

```py
def get_tokens_price(tokenIds: array) -> dict[str, float]:
```

`array` is the wrong type annotation. This is not an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)<sup>1</sup> - this is a list of strings. `list[str]` .

---

```py
tokens = None
for token in tokenIds:
    tokens = f'{tokens}, {token}'
tokensList = cg.get_price(ids=tokens, vs_currencies='usd')
```

No need for a for loop here - just use `str.join`.

```py
tokens_list = cg.get_price(ids=",".join(token_ids), vs_currencies='usd')
```

---

You also construct a list of NamedTuples, just to use it to construct the dictionary that you return. Just construct the dictionary directly, and get rid of `CryptoCurrency`. You can also use `dict.items()` to iterate over `(key, value)` pairs directly.

```py
currencies = {currency: prices['usd'] for currency, prices in tokens_list.items()}
```

---

Full code:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
saved_tokens = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum']

def get_token_prices(token_ids: list[str]) -> dict[str, float]:
    tokens_list = cg.get_price(ids=",".join(token_ids), vs_currencies='usd')
    currencies = {name: prices['usd'] for name, prices in tokens_list.items()}
    return currencies

prices = get_token_prices(saved_tokens)
print(prices)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> arrays are a specialized type that are used for storing large sequences of numerical data.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks a lot for this answer.
The most helpful part was about str.join ;)
In this case, I'm using NamedTuple incorrectly, but now my project is larger and all function inputs and outputs use the "CryptoCurrency" class, as far as I understand, is this the right move now?

As for arrays, this was of course a mistake, the list was meant and used, thanks, I read about their differences.

Comment: It depends on whether the NamedTuple is being used meaningfully. If it helps to clarify your code structure, then go for it. If it instead jjust acts as an unnecessary intermediate that complicates the code (as in the question's code), then I would suggest against using it.